# How to use p5.sound in Typescript + Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, p5.js

I'm JavaScript beginner.
I am not English native and I'm sorry for my poor English.

Now I want to do sound visualization with Node.js + Typescript, but I don't know how to load sound in `setup()`. Please teach me how to load sound in Node.js + Typescript.

I tried importing `'p5/lib/addons/p5.sound'`. But I don't know how to use this module in `sketch` of below code.

main.ts

```
import * as p5 from 'p5';

const sketch = (p: p5) => {
  p.setup = () => {
    p.resizeCanvas(100, 100);
    // want to load sound here
  };
  p.draw = () => {
    p.background(100);
  }
};

const sketchP = new p5(sketch);
```

global.d.ts

```
import module = require('p5');

export = module;
export as namespace p5;
declare global {
    interface Window {
        p5: typeof module
    }
}
```

Comment: To load a sound with p5.js you use loadSound. Take a look at https://p5js.org/examples/sound-load-and-play-sound.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I understand that I load sound using `loadSound()`. However, method `loadSound()` is the module `'p5/lib/addons/p5.sound'` but `p` in the above code is the module `'p5'`. So I could not load sounds only to write `loadSound()` in `setup` simply.

Answer (score 5):

Now I resolve the problem. Thank you.

main.ts

```
require('p5/lib/addons/p5.sound')

const sketch = function(p: p5) {
  let sound: p5.SoundFile;

  p.preload = () => {
    const loadSound = (path: string) =>
            ((p as any) as p5.SoundFile).loadSound(path);
    sound = loadSound("../audio/demo.mp3")
  };

  p.setup = () => {
    p.resizeCanvas(100, 100);
    sound.play()
  };
}
```